# inserting new record in the Ms access 2007 and VB 6

Tags: vb6

Please help with the syntax in adodc syntax on add, update, delete, my database is microsoft access 2007

i used add this way

```
adodc1.recordset.addnew
```

what happened is that it only changed the values from the first entry of my database, what do i have to do add a new entry and not overwrite my first entry?

Answer (score 0):

```
adodc1.recordset.addnew
adodc1.recordset.fieldname=fieldvalue
...
adodc1.recordset.update
```